# Rodar imagem do marker google maps não funcionando

Tags: javascript, google-maps, marker

Bom estou precisando rodar a imagem do icone de acordo com o header que chega para mim.

Estou tentando fazer de varias formar porém nenhuma delas funcionou, vamos la aos códigos.

**PRIMEIRA TENTATIVA [PATH DO ICONE]**

```
 this.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(location.coords.latitude, location.coords.longitude),
  map: this.map,
  optimized: false,
  icon: {
    PATH: 'meu path',
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    size: new google.maps.Size(32, 32)
  },
})
```

Esta maneira funcionou porém o `svg` que preciso é complexo, ele tem mais de um `path`, se eu consegui-se junta-los em um `path` apenas, seria interessantíssimo e tudo funcionaria como precisava.

*Então o problema desta tentativa é referente a um svg com vários paths o rotate funciona perfeitamente.*

**SEGUNDA TENTATIVA [URL SVG]**

```
this.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(location.coords.latitude, location.coords.longitude),
  map: this.map,
  optimized: false,
  icon: {
    url: 'assets/img/maps/if_map-marker_299087.svg',
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    size: new google.maps.Size(32, 32)
  },
});
```

Nesta opção meu problema está quando vou aplicar o `rotate` na imagem, estou fazendo assim:

```
document.querySelector('.gmnoprint img').setAttribute('style', 'transform:rotate(-134deg);');
```

porém  não está funcionando como preciso. Ele adiciona tudo certo no html mas no momento de pegar o comando fica como se o fundo da imagem tive-se girando mas permanecesse no mesmo local; Na imagem do lado podemos ver o quadrado de azul (quando coloco o mouse em cima da imagem) e a imagem em si, o quadrado está rodando porém a imagem não.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**TERCEIRA TENTATIVA [URL IMG]**

Nesta tentativa utilizei os mesmo métodos da tentativa 2 utilizando imagem em png, o resultado foi o mesmo.

**INFORMAÇÕES DO PROJETO**

```
@angular: 5.0.2
@types/googlemaps: 3.30.0
typescript: ^2.6.1
```

Answer (score -1):

Existia uma lib JS chamada **MarkerWithlabel** em que você podia atribuir uma imagem como marcador, e inclusive digitar um texto em cima da imagem. No seu caso, você pode usar qualquer imagem, se rotacionar a imagem desse marcador e atribuir no atributo icon da variável marker *(do exemplo abaixo)* acho que funciona do jeito que você quer.

Você pode usar essa [documentação Não-Oficial](https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/tree/master/markerwithlabel) para ver

Seu uso basicamente era:

```js
 var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
   position: homeLatLng, // usa o 'new google.maps.LatLng()'
   draggable: true,  // true or false
   map: map,   // mapa que vai receber o marcador
   labelContent: "$425K",  // Texto em cima da imagem
   labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(22, 0),
   labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
   labelStyle: {opacity: 0.75},
   icon: 'img/markers/marker_patrol.png' // SUBSTITUI A IMAGEM AQUI
 });
```

Comment: Acrescente mais informações sobre o plugin, modo de instalar e tudo mais, teria como /;

Comment: No link da documentação q eu mandei, entra na pasta SRC e baixa aquele markerwithlabel.js.
Inclua ele no seu projeto onde achar conveniente, não esqueça de importar o script (normalmente feito no index.html usando a tag <script>.
Simples assim.
Na documentação ainda tem exemplos (na pasta examples) e maiores detalhes da documentação na pasta DOCS.